# Convert dd/mmm/yyyy to yyyy-mm-dd

Tags: hive, unix-timestamp

I have a date in this format:

```
08/Jul/2012:06:19:00 -0200
```

and I am trying to do select like:

```
from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(substr(hiredate,0,10),'dd/MMM/yyyy HH:mm:ss'),'yyyy-MM-dd')
```

But it's not working. I want to convert it into `2012-07-08`. I'm using `quickstart cloudera 5.12`.

Comment: thank you emix for editing it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See if this two-step process works for you:

1. convert a string from this unusual format to `unixtimestamp`
2. format the `unixtimestamp` (result from step 1) to a desired form

```
0: jdbc:hive2://beeline> select from_unixtime(unix_timestamp('08/Jul/2012:06:19:00 -0200','dd/MMM/yyyy:HH:mm:ss Z'),'yyyy-MM-dd') d;

+-------------+--+
|      d      |
+-------------+--+
| 2012-07-08  |
+-------------+--+
1 row selected (0.825 seconds)
```

Comment: thank you mazaneicha. it worked. can you please tell me what is Z and d.

Comment: `Z` is zone offset (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html), `d` is simply a column alias (heading) :).

Comment: if i want to insert this date into hive dynamic partition (partitioned by yyyy string,mm string,dd string), then how to use it in insert statement.

Comment: You'd probably use `year`, `month` and `day` functions on it https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF. And if you get stuck, just post a separate question :)